# Error 69 86 while loading key in RFID card reader

Tags: rfid, mifare, pcsc

I'm trying to load keys in volatile and non-volatile memory of my card-reader Omnikey 5421 and I got the error answer **69 86**
The load command is:
`FF 82 00 01 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF  or FF 82 20 01 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF`

The answer is always **69 86**.
For authenticate command the answer is the same
`FF 86 00 00 05 01 00 00 60 00` result is :  **69 86**

The only successful command is getting the UID
`FF CA 00 00 00`  => 30 1A 5A 0D 90 00
My system is Win7 64.
Please help to solve the problem.

Comment: That is strange as `FF 82 20 01 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF` works for me with MIFARE Classic card on Omnikey 6321 reader. Are you sure it is a MIFARE Classic card?

Comment: What about this note from the developer guide(can't verify it right now): OMNIKEY Contactless Smart Card reader firmware version 5.00 is the first to support 
all keys listed above. Readers with firmware version 1.03 and 1.04 only support key 
numbers 0x20 and 0xF0.

Answer (score 0):

Please try command.

```
FF 82 00 60 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF ( 0x60 to use the Key A)
```

or

```
FF 82 00 61 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF ( 0x61 to use the Key B)
```

Comment: I tried both  
FF82006006FFFFFFFFFFFF  or
FF82006106FFFFFFFFFFFF  
and  
FF82206006FFFFFFFFFFFF  
FF82206106FFFFFFFFFFFF  

The answer is always  6986. According to pcsc spec the error is 'Volatile memory is not available'
But why do I get this error when I try to load keys in non-volatile mamory with P1='20'?